# Laptop not coming back from sleep after lid close

Tags: laptop, lid

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an ROG Strix GL553. I have a problem when I close the laptop lid. The computer goes to sleep but when I open it back again it gets stuck on a black screen.

I belive there's something wrong with the Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050 drivers. I'm not sure how can I solve this, installing nvidia-current driver makes computer stuck on login.

Edit: I tried suspending the laptop manually and same thing happens, screen remains black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NVMe SSD suspend/resume is a know bug

This problem has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1655100) and [ArchLinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=216520). The solution is to edit `/etc/default/grub` with `sudo` powers and find the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpiphp.disable=1"
```

Your options will be different but add the option `acpihp.disable=1` between the double quotes.

Save the file then reboot. Now suspend and resume will work.

## What does `acpiphp.disable=1` do?

According to the [kernel developer](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2436731/) in 2013 this disables ACPI hot-plugging. However that doesn't mean hot-plugging is disabled on your machine. For example, replugging the USB cord to your Android phone brings up Nautilus to view files as it should. Also power cycling a second TV connected to your laptop via USB-C ThunderBolt 3 to Displayport to HDMI adapter reorganizes windows across workspaces as it should.

## Proposed permanent fix

A few days ago a permanent fix was proposed in [kernel `4.15.0-23`](https://people.canonical.com/%7Ekhfeng/lp1655100-2/) by someone who is probably a Ubuntu Developer.

Comment: Sorry, I had mi PC reformated. I had to use so I couldn't wait for a solution, thanks anyways for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Do you mean you had it reformatted to Windows 10 or something else?

Comment: Is it `acpihp` or `acpiphp`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for pointing out the typo.